# What is this topic called? I want to learn more. Server-Client Synchronization

Tags: design-patterns, model, client-server

This is a topic that has been part of almost every application I've ever worked on and yet I don't have a good name for it.  I'd love to learn more about best practices and ideally find books/research on the topic but I don't even have a name for it to Google.  I'm hoping I can describe the topic here and people can point me towards a name, or even better, books, which discuss the topic.

What I've been calling it now is server-client synchronization.  It's the practice of sending notifications to clients to update them when the game state has changed.  The best way to describe it is with an example.

As an example consider a web-based game of Spades that is in progress.  The currently active player plays a card and takes the trick.  Several changes happen in the server side model as a result of this.  The trick is cleared, the player has a new trick, the game possibly ended, etc.

This information needs to be communicated with the clients and there is a whole slew of options.  Most likely the server is going to send events in some way (these events may even be sent by polling).  The events could simply say "Player 3 played the 8 of Spades" and force the client to figure out all the corresponding changes in the model.  The events could be as detailed as, "8 of Spades moved from player 3's hand to the board, the trick was cleared, player 3 gained a new trick".

So again, my question is.  What is this topic called and how do I find books/discussions on best patterns and practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may mean "lock step" synchronization.

Or just google "net code", "client side prediction".

Age of empires (lock step), quake, tribes and counter-strike are some of many games that have great articles about their network code (net code).

Answer (score 1):

This book was once suggested to me for something similar. I don't know whether you'll find it useful, but here it goes:

```
Networked Graphics
Building Networked Games and Virtual Environments
Author(s): Anthony Steed and Manuel Fradinho Oliveira
ISBN: 978-0-12-374423-4
```

If you look for it on Amazon, you can see the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: @Raynos: Oh really? I think it has everything to do with it. From the link I posted: The essence of the Observer Pattern is to "Define a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically."

Comment: The observer pattern is great, especially in desktop applications where the server model is accessible as part of the same program.  It's not the entire answer.  Certainly not in a web application where the server is remote.  Even then, the notification mechanism is only part of a much larger picture.

Comment: This pattern is not architecture-dependent. It is a principle. You can implement it with whatever technology you want. The idea behind is that observers are notified of changes when they occur.

Comment: @Tudor the question is how do you do synchronize data _over_ a _network_. Unless you talk about synchronization strategies or network communication strategies, it's simply noise.

Comment: It's tagged "design patterns". Also from the question text: "It's the practice of sending notifications to clients to update them when the game state has changed." Sounds like observer to me...